# How create folder from function parameter google script

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How to create folder from function parameter
example

```
 function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file,namaf) {
 try {
 namafolder=namaf;
 createFolder([namafolder];
 }
 }
```

Not create from variables like

```
var name ="Myfoldernanme";
var newfolder = folder.createFolder(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of DocsList and DriveApp can be useful.

```
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function main() {
  var parentFolder = DocsList.getFolder('September 2017');
  var idNewFolder = parentFolder.createFolder('New Folder').getId();
  var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(idNewFolder);
  newFolder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
}
```